# How to upload on google store from country Georgia(not on the list)

Tags: android, google-play, playback

Me and my friend just made the applications for androids and wanted to register and then upload them on the google store(play store), but our country(Georgia) is not on the list. It was surprise for us, because all of our neighbors have access.

Comment: If thats true, theres nothing anyone here could help and probably off-topic. [This list](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286) however suggests that the play store is available Georgia for both Free and Paid Apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a VPN if it is blocked in your country. It could also be that it has to be done via a different route.
That being said, I don't know if there are any consequences regarding payments and bank accounts when you sign up in a different country.

Comment: The case is that when we have to choose country, it brings zip code, address and everything. I think that we can use someone's address from other country.

Comment: If you have some relatives living abroad I guess that's the solution then. Or  maybe in app purchases instead of just purchasing the app through the Play Store?

Comment: My application should be free on the store, I just don't know, what to do.

Comment: If you don't plan on making any revenue through the app you can always just put it under a fake name / address. Or you could try to get in touch with Google support.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I think this question is better suited for android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks a lot )) and if you know is it legal to set offline banners in my application? for example if X company wants to set offline advertisements in my app, can I do it without asking google store?

Comment: I think it is, there are some quite popular game publishers that use this technique so that if you disable internet connections you still get served ads. But don't take my word for it, if I was you I'd look it up on law.stackexchange.com or something. I am by no means an expert.